# Websphere connection pool issue i.e DSRA9110E

Tags: websphere, database-connection

```
LOGGER.debug("Connection Status Disb isClosed = " + conn.isClosed()); 
// returns true.
crsDisbDetailstmp = DataAccess.getData("select 1 cnt from dual", conn, new String[] {});
crsDisbDetailstmp.first();
LOGGER.debug("crsDisbDetailstmp"+ crsDisbDetailstmp.getString("cnt"));

DataAccess.executeProc("PRC_MCLR_TRNPRCDTL", new String[]{strOrgId, strAccountid,strFixedRate ,strModifiers }, conn);
```

> Exception occured while executing last statement i.e execute procedure.
>   Exception=com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.

I search a lot on google it shows this exception is occurred because connection is closed also i checked with conn.isclosed() which return true..
But If connection is closed then how i am able to fire select queries???
Please help me to figure it out as i worked on JBOSS only and first time on Websphere

Comment: you should not be able to issue any sort of operations on a closed `Connection` (aside from `close()` or `isClosed()`).  Do you know why the connection is closed?  Do you intend it to be closed at this point?

Comment: Yes , Connection is getting closed by 'conn.close()' which is present in finally block of method account_summary and this method is called just before the above code.But i am getting confused if it is showing connection is closed then how it is executing and select statement with the same connection object

Comment: I configured "useConnectionPoolForPolling =  true " .

Comment: Have you confirmed that `DataAccess.getData()` does indeed use the connection that is being passed in?  And not some other connection?

Comment: @AndyGuibert you are right i.e I forgot to check in DataAccess we written one method in that if connection object is null or closed then it is creating new connection where as in DataAccess only the method to call Procedure does not contain the respective method for new connection...Issue Resolved..Thank you..